# Apache2 server using all resources

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04

I am very new to server administration and have been running a web server off of a VPS with 2 GB of RAM and 2 cores using Ubuntu. It has been running very well for the past couple months but today the Apache 2 process started using a TON of resources, all of the ram and CPU power. I have no idea why this is happening and I have no idea what to do.  The traffic has not gone up. When I run `ps aux` I get the following apache procedures

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
www-data  4710  3.9  1.8 356984 38488 ?        R    16:04   0:30 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5438  3.7  1.8 356972 37828 ?        R    16:04   0:28 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5441  3.5  1.9 357156 39056 ?        R    16:04   0:27 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5450  4.5  2.2 359420 46144 ?        R    16:04   0:34 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5498  3.7  1.8 357228 38248 ?        R    16:04   0:28 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5499  3.8  1.8 357228 37172 ?        R    16:04   0:29 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5500  4.0  1.8 357232 38232 ?        R    16:04   0:30 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5505  3.9  1.7 352292 34768 ?        S    16:04   0:29 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5508  3.6  2.0 357488 40988 ?        R    16:04   0:27 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5513  3.9  1.6 351324 33812 ?        S    16:04   0:29 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5515  3.9  1.5 352276 32024 ?        S    16:04   0:29 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5521  3.9  1.5 352276 32068 ?        S    16:04   0:29 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5523  3.7  1.9 357424 39748 ?        R    16:04   0:28 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5526  3.7  1.8 357168 38468 ?        R    16:05   0:27 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5530  3.8  1.7 357168 36696 ?        R    16:05   0:28 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5532  3.6  1.8 357204 37512 ?        R    16:05   0:26 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5533  3.7  1.7 356984 36480 ?        R    16:05   0:27 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5535  3.9  1.5 352284 32052 ?        S    16:05   0:29 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5553  4.0  1.6 352360 34124 ?        S    16:05   0:29 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5554  3.6  1.8 357228 38084 ?        R    16:05   0:27 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5560  3.9  1.7 356868 35600 ?        R    16:05   0:29 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5562  4.0  1.6 352296 34080 ?        S    16:05   0:29 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5563  3.9  1.8 356976 37716 ?        R    16:05   0:28 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5564  3.3  1.9 357228 40808 ?        R    16:05   0:24 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5615  3.9  1.8 357232 38064 ?        R    16:05   0:28 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5620  3.9  1.7 356860 35648 ?        R    16:05   0:28 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5621  3.6  1.7 356912 36384 ?        R    16:05   0:26 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5622  3.7  1.8 357120 37712 ?        R    16:05   0:26 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5626  3.6  1.8 357224 38076 ?        R    16:05   0:25 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5648  3.7  1.6 356872 34476 ?        R    16:05   0:26 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5650  3.7  1.9 357156 39468 ?        R    16:05   0:26 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5652  3.7  1.7 357072 36376 ?        R    16:05   0:26 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5653  3.9  1.8 357232 38076 ?        R    16:05   0:27 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5704  3.8  1.6 356904 34520 ?        R    16:05   0:25 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5709  3.9  1.7 356860 35584 ?        R    16:06   0:26 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5713  3.5  1.8 357012 37908 ?        R    16:06   0:23 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5722  3.6  1.7 357156 36644 ?        R    16:06   0:24 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5726  3.6  1.7 356828 35560 ?        R    16:06   0:25 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5731  3.7  1.7 357124 36368 ?        R    16:06   0:25 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5752  3.6  1.7 356828 35552 ?        R    16:06   0:24 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5757  3.7  1.7 356860 35716 ?        R    16:06   0:25 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5763  3.7  1.7 356860 35648 ?        R    16:06   0:25 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5862  3.8  1.7 356960 36364 ?        R    16:07   0:22 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5945  0.5  1.9 355244 40696 ?        S    16:11   0:01 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5947  1.5  2.0 357016 41352 ?        R    16:11   0:04 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5979  2.4  1.8 357252 38160 ?        R    16:12   0:06 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  5998  0.5  1.7 352608 36556 ?        S    16:13   0:01 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6001  2.5  2.0 357140 41368 ?        R    16:13   0:06 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6022  2.8  1.9 357092 39736 ?        R    16:13   0:07 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6041  1.9  1.9 357012 40380 ?        R    16:13   0:04 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6050  0.7  1.9 355292 39180 ?        S    16:14   0:01 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6055  0.6  2.0 354436 41344 ?        S    16:15   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6060  0.2  1.9 356532 38988 ?        S    16:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6071  0.5  1.7 355032 35948 ?        S    16:16   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6075  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6077  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6078  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6082  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6083  1.2  1.9 357852 38924 ?        R    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6084  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6085  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6086  1.5  1.5 351152 31268 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6087  2.7  2.0 359512 42132 ?        R    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6088  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6089  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6090  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6091  1.5  1.5 352428 32492 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6092  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6093  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6094  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6095  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6096  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6097  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6098  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6099  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6100  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6101  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6102  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6103  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6104  1.8  1.5 351152 31268 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6105  2.4  1.8 357204 37544 ?        R    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6106  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6107  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6114  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6115  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6116  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6117  1.8  1.7 355028 36544 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6118  1.8  1.7 355028 36532 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6119  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6121  1.5  1.6 350632 32812 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6122  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6123  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6125  1.6  1.8 357416 38472 ?        R    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6126  1.4  1.7 357824 36292 ?        R    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6127  1.1  1.9 358156 40140 ?        R    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6129  1.1  1.6 356864 34468 ?        R    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6130  0.0  0.3 349804  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6133  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    16:17   0:00 [apache2] <defu
www-data  6134  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6135  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6136  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6137  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6138  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6139  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6140  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6141  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6142  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6143  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6144  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
www-data  6145  0.0  0.3 349764  8116 ?        S    16:17   0:00 /usr/sbin/apach
```

First of all this is a TON of processes and a lot of them are using a TON of CPU.  I am not sure what other information I should give you.  Why is this happening and how can I stop it?  Do I need to get a more powerful server or just change something in the configuration.

**EDIT MORE INFO**

I am running PHP with a joomla CMS.

*ps auxf output for www-data user*

```
www-data  7416  3.8  2.0 357216 41332 ?        R    16:52   0:12  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7432  8.9  2.0 357232 41072 ?        R    16:53   0:27  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7437 10.5  1.8 357228 37312 ?        R    16:53   0:33  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7438  1.6  1.9 357088 38848 ?        R    16:53   0:05  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7442  9.5  1.7 351752 35636 ?        R    16:53   0:29  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7443 18.9  1.7 357152 35308 ?        R    16:53   0:59  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7451 14.6  1.7 357156 35292 ?        R    16:53   0:45  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7455  9.4  1.9 354672 39148 ?        S    16:53   0:29  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7465 18.6  1.8 357164 37244 ?        R    16:53   0:57  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7477  4.9  1.8 356968 37144 ?        R    16:53   0:15  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7479  4.6  1.9 357168 40412 ?        R    16:53   0:14  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  7480  5.0  1.8 357216 37372 ?        R    16:53   0:15  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  8570 12.0  1.6 356904 32896 ?        R    16:54   0:28  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9564  6.4  1.8 357168 37236 ?        R    16:55   0:12  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9574  5.0  1.8 357008 36900 ?        R    16:55   0:08  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9577  2.8  1.8 357220 37256 ?        R    16:55   0:04  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9583  4.5  1.9 357168 39020 ?        R    16:55   0:07  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9589  1.5  2.2 359304 46208 ?        R    16:55   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9592  4.7  1.7 357160 35616 ?        R    16:55   0:07  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9601  4.1  1.9 357432 40404 ?        R    16:55   0:06  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9602  3.0  2.2 359296 45732 ?        R    16:55   0:04  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9605  7.3  1.6 356860 34208 ?        R    16:55   0:11  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9613  2.4  1.9 357212 40452 ?        R    16:55   0:03  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9626  0.9  1.6 351060 34680 ?        S    16:55   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9627  7.3  1.6 356864 32904 ?        R    16:55   0:11  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9634  6.7  1.6 356860 34208 ?        R    16:55   0:10  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9636  4.9  1.8 357228 37248 ?        R    16:55   0:07  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9637  3.3  1.8 357204 36848 ?        R    16:55   0:05  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9638  2.7  1.8 357104 38548 ?        R    16:55   0:04  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9643  6.3  1.6 356904 32960 ?        R    16:55   0:09  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9644  6.3  1.6 356864 32968 ?        R    16:55   0:09  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9647  5.2  1.7 357168 35268 ?        R    16:55   0:08  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9649  6.4  1.6 356864 32904 ?        R    16:55   0:09  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9651  3.4  1.7 356996 36652 ?        R    16:55   0:05  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9652  3.4  2.2 359296 46524 ?        R    16:55   0:05  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9653  2.7  1.8 357168 37216 ?        R    16:55   0:04  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9705  2.4  1.7 357160 35272 ?        R    16:57   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9712  4.0  1.7 357208 36572 ?        R    16:57   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9722  4.1  1.6 356864 32968 ?        R    16:57   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9723  2.3  1.6 356880 32960 ?        R    16:57   0:01  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9724  4.1  1.6 356864 32968 ?        R    16:57   0:02  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9735  0.4  1.5 351784 32268 ?        R    16:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9736  2.0  1.8 356968 36988 ?        R    16:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9737  0.7  1.5 352428 31096 ?        S    16:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9741  3.6  1.6 356864 32968 ?        R    16:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9745  3.5  1.6 356864 32968 ?        R    16:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9746  3.7  1.6 356864 33032 ?        R    16:57   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9755  0.8  1.5 352476 32396 ?        S    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9757  0.8  1.5 352428 31060 ?        S    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9758  1.7  1.5 352440 31096 ?        S    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9765  0.0  0.4 350000  9572 ?        S    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9766  0.0  0.3 349804  8072 ?        S    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9767  0.0  0.3 349804  8072 ?        S    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9775  0.8  1.2 351272 25808 ?        S    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9776  3.3  1.9 357428 39796 ?        R    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9777  3.4  1.6 356864 32972 ?        R    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9780  2.8  1.6 356864 32908 ?        R    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9782  2.6  1.6 356864 32968 ?        R    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9783  2.5  1.7 358144 35912 ?        R    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9789  0.1  1.0 351728 21296 ?        R    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9790  0.1  1.0 351696 21264 ?        R    16:58   0:00  \_ /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  9791  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        Z    16:58   0:00  \_ [apache2] <defunct>
```

*cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*

http://pastebin.com/bCUrv1E7

*netstat -ntpl*

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:SQLPORT          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2821/mysqld
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:SSHPORT             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2774/sshd
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      7397/apache2
tcp6       0      0 :::SSHPORT                  :::*                    LISTEN      2774/sshd
```

Comment: Are you using a CMS like wordpress? I bet your getting attacked. Similar to `DOS`. It's just typically not big enough for the host to notice but it will hose your server up with a high load until it becomes unresponsive.

Comment: @PanamaJack I have cloud flare enabled

Answer (score 0):

What else is running on this server? What is the nature of the web application? Is it PHP? Python? Ruby?

Can you post the output of the following please:

1) ps auxf

2) cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/*

3) netstat -ntpl

This should help us track this down further,

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: I'm tempted to agree with @panamaJack on this one.  Check your logs for a large number of requests from a single IP Address or a single URL being accessed by large numbers of multiple IP Addresses.

If you're running Joomla, make sure it has been updated to the latest version.

It's also worth checking the mail logs on that server, Joomla often gets hacked and has mass mailers uploaded to it (five years of running a hosting platform with > 50K Joomla installs taught me that!) so lots of email outbound is a sign you may have been hacked.

Comment: So the access log in that location has no data, but the error log has some reports that have only been generated today!  I think I am getting closer to finding the issue.  There are multiple occurrences of the following line `[Tue Feb 10 17:12:24.979034 2015] [core:notice] [pid 10029] AH00052: child pid 10047 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)` and with many other pids.  I am now researching how to fix Segmentation faults, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also I checked my mail.log and all of the lines logged are from today and there are a LOT of lines logged just in today, over 1 million.  Other than that I have no idea how to read this or what it means?  How can I tell if this is the issue and if my system is hacked and there is a mass mailer occurring?

Comment: Can you post some of the content of your mail log and error log to pastebin or similar? 

Set the apache server process to "DEBUG" logging and restart it to give us some more information.

Comment: As for the mail log, this kind of just gets logged thousands of times http://pastebin.com/cwmfp5wA.  As for Apache the only thing in the error log is that line I posted above many many times, I have turned log level to debug and will be on the look out for anything new.

Comment: a quick google reveals http://serverfault.com/questions/58052/what-is-sensible-mda-and-do-i-need-it - the answer? Install sendmail/postfix/exim and make sure it is configured correctly.

Then check your email logs and see what's going on.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Yup! bug in my code, I never changed any of the code, but the client entered in-incorrect data which sent the script into an infinite loop!  I guess this is why you should always make sure you are getting the right type of data you want.  Anyways, I cannot thank you enough for the help you supplied, I know so much more about apache and ubuntu because of this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I have 1 GB RAM, 1 WordPress and 1 Laravel platform.

I had activated two `.conf` files in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`:
`example1.conf` and `example2.conf`

**Solution**:

In my case I had a `.conf` file that did not contribute at all, so I disabled it.

```
sudo a2dissite example2.conf
```

Then restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```